# Looking up data in two columns

Tags: excel

I have a question regarding the vlookup function or any other ways which could help me derive to this outcome.

I have 3 columns of data, A,B & C.

I would like to identify any data in column A that comes up in column C.

Then, I would like the new column D to reflect the data in column B in the same row as the match found in column A.

I am sorry if this is confusing.

Here is the example;

A1 - 1
A2 - 2
A3 - 3
A4 - 4
A5 - 5

B1 - abc
B2 - def
B3 - ghi
B4 - jkl
B5 - mno

C1 - 2
C2 - 4
C3 - 5
C4 - 7
C5 - 9

I would like D to look for a match from column C in column A and reflect the data in column B.
This would be the result I need.

D1 - def
D2 - jkl
D3 - mno
D4 - 
D5 -

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a simple `VLOOKUP` formula - enter this in D1 and copy it down:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,A:B,2,0)
```

Even better than `VLOOKUP` is `INDEX`/`MATCH`, i.e. this formula:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C1,A:A,0))
```

Both approaches lead to the same result, the later is a bit more robust when you change your sheet structure.